# What to do with electrically charged vinyl

Tags: vinyl

I begun buying vinyl LPs some weeks ago. Some records are very electrically charged.
This is mainly the case for new records, not for used ones. 
Is there a method to uncharge them?

Comment: http://foxmusic.hubpages.com/hub/VinylRecordsAndStatic - gives some hints . . .

Comment: And - http://www.head-fi.org/t/295317/vinyl-static - And - http://forums.stevehoffman.tv/threads/static-electricity-on-vinyl.227207/

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer; that way it can't get down votes… because this subject is one of those that has vinyl junkies frothing at the mouth over the latest, greatest, static-removing gun/wipe/spray… all a total waste of time & effort. Use a standard old style velvet cloth with a sponge back… run it under the tap first, then squeeze it dry. Picks up dust & grounds the vinyl though you. Done.

Comment: I really like the suggestion of Tetsujin. Is there any risk to damage the vinyl?

Comment: @derBasti - very little risk, unless you manage to press hard enough to pop the drive belt (v unlikely) or are unfortunate enough to capture a nasty piece of grit under the cloth. Gently does it & all should be fine- been a vinyl user since the 70's & haven't managed to do either yet ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Using a Zerostat gun seems to be a widespread method of removing electric charge from vinyl records